# Is it possibile to “slice” a Modal in Ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

i’m trying to make something like the image shown below.

[image: Example]

The “pop-up” is swipable and all three elements closes toghether

I tried with Modals but i think i cannot call 3 different modals at the same time or “slice” a modal in three pieces showing different content.

Another option could be using multipleToasts but i can’t put HTML (images, link ecc) into a toast and, afterall, this isn’t the purpose of this kind of Ionic Component.

So, any ideas?
Any kind of help is very appreciated

Comment: Did you try with https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/action-sheet?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet use this link

Comment: Yeah this could be a nice idea, but i can't put HTML into action-sheet buttons, so i think its not the right component for my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using a modal with transparent background and ion-cards